# IBM Bluemix Error

Tags: eclipse, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push a project from Eclipse to IBM Bluemix. I am getting the following errors:

```
[ERROR ] CWWKZ0202E: Unable to install bundle com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector_1.0.0.20141128-1523 [110] with context root /IBMMGMTRest into the web container.

[err] java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: Connection refused DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42502, Error Code = -438

[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:747)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.096-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:66)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.097-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:135)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.098-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.q(y.java:859)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.098-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.completeSqlca(Connection.java:5089)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.099-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.l(y.java:536)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.099-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.p(y.java:715)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.100-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.d(y.java:151)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.101-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.k(b.java:1385)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.101-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1297)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.102-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:6426)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.103-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:764)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.103-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:847)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.104-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:422)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.104-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:397)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.105-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:335)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.106-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnectionX(DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:348)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.106-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PooledConnection.<init>(DB2PooledConnection.java:83)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.107-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource.java:131)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.107-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1198)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.108-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.108-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1214)
2016-01-20T15:01:15.109-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at [internal classes]
2016-01-20T15:01:15.116-0500[App/0]ERR[err] at main.SqlConnection.connectFromWebserver(SqlConnection.java:32)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: SQL Status 42502 means "The authorization ID does not have the privilege to perform the operation as specified."

Answer (score 3):

This error message in the SQL exception

> [err] java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: Connection refused DSRA0010E: SQL State = 42502, Error Code = -438

gives enough information of what could be the reason of your problem: it means that your are (really probably) trying to connect to the wrong port or to the wrong service.

Check your database connection parameters, from your tag I suppose you are trying to connect to DB2, so for example if your have bound a SQLDB service check the VCAP_SERVICE host and port configuration.